# Android, PHP, MySQL

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have a user login in Android using PHP and MySQL server. While I run the program, I get error message:

> org.apache.http.nohttpresponseexception the target server failed to respond

and:

> Java.lang.NullPointerException

Can somebody can help me? This is my MySQL Server address http://pati-tourism.web.id/idesolusi/select_user.php.

This is code in MainActivityLogin:

```
    class AttemptingLogin extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivityLogin.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Login...");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int success;

        username = user.getText().toString();
        password = pass.getText().toString();
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

        JSONObject object = jsonParser
                .getRequest(URL_LOGIN, "POST", params);
        try {
            success = object.getInt("success");
            if (success == 1) {
                return "1";
            } else {
                return "0";
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        if (result != null && result.equals("1")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivityLogin.this,
                    MainActivityEvent.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Code in JsonParser:

```
public JSONObject getRequest(String url, String method, List<NameValuePair> params){

    try {
        if(method == "POST"){
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if (method == "GET") {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "Utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line+"\n");              
        }
        is.close();
        json = builder.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error Converting Result : "+e.toString());
    }

    //try parse the string to a JSON Object
    try {
        jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Parsing data error : "+e.toString());
    }

    return jsonObj;
}
```

Comment: What happens if you hit that address from the device in a web browser?

Comment: sorry, I reply just now
I solve this problem already
Thank you

Comment: You might consider answering your own question if you think it would be helpful to others.